# sql query appears in the outpout of spool command(file.txt)

Tags: sql

i want to save the result of a query using spool command.
But i got the query and its output in the result file (result.txt)

```
 spool "result.txt"
 select * from table;
 spool off
```

how can i remove the query from the file result.txt?

Comment: You need to provide the database you are using and the tool where you are righting that command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following set command:

```
  set termout off
```

If you store the complete script in a script file (for instance getData.sql) and then run it from SQL Plus with the following command you will have the results wanted.

```
@getData.sql
```

Note that typing these commands directly in SQL Plus will cause the *select* statement to be in the file, even with the set parameter.

Comment: yes, i have to put the query in a script file.
thanks :)